# Solution of equation $y''+x^2y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, sturm-liouville

Does equation $y''+x^2y=0,$ where $y$ is function of $x$ have explicit solution? Perhaps with some conditions or in special case? I came across that when we have $x$ instead of $x^2,$ solutions are connected with some Airy functions.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%2Bx%5E2y%3D0) says yes in terms of the [Parabolic Cylinder Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function), to be precise: $y(x) = c_1 D_{-1/2}((1 + i) x) + c_2 D_{-1/2}((-1 + i) x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
As pointed out in the comments, understanding differential equations like yours leads to the parabolic cylinder functions. In particular, the standard form
$$\frac{\d^2 y}{\d x^2}+(\tfrac{1}{4}x^2-a)y=0$$
([DLMF 12.2.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2.E3))
admits standard solution
$$y(x)=c_+W(a,x)+c_-W(a,-x)$$
where $W(a,x)$ is chosen to satisfy the initial conditions
$$\begin{align}W\left(a,0\right)&=2^{-\frac{3}{4}}\left|\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{%
1}{2}ia\right)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{4}+\tfrac{1}{2}ia\right)}\right|^{\frac{%
1}{2}},\\
W'\left(a,0\right)&=-2^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left|\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{4}+%
\tfrac{1}{2}ia\right)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}+\tfrac{1}{2}ia\right)}\right|^%
{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$$
([DLMF 12.14.ii](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.14.ii)). However, in the special case $a=0$, $W$ is expressible in terms of fractional-order Bessel functions:
$$W\left(0,\pm x\right)=2^{-\frac{5}{4}}\sqrt{\pi x}\left(J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(%
\tfrac{1}{4}x^{2}\right)\mp J_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\tfrac{1}{4}x^{2}\right)%
\right)$$
([DLMF 12.14.13](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.14.E13)).